# if range of cells contains string then goto

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is a topic that is talks about a lot, but I just cant find the answer.

I have a range. if in that range there is a word then I need it to go to the next code. if not, than skip the next code and move on.

I'm unable to define the range.

this is my code:

```
For a = 4 To 20
    If (Range("H" & a).Value = "*nice*") Then
        GoTo Clean 
    Else
        GoTo pre
    End If
Next
```

In the range I do have the word "nice" but it still skips clean and goes straight to pre.

whats wrong? how do i define my range and how can the code understand that in my range the word nice" IS IN there.

Comment: I think a part of your range's value has nice. In that case you should use `InStr(1, Range("H" & a).Value, "nice", vbTextCompare) > 0`

Comment: @aj_bk have you tried any of the answers below ? any feedbacks would be nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Like` with the wildcard (`*`) before and after "nice", like :

```
If Range("H" & a).Value Like "*nice*" Then
```

Adding this line into your entire code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestLike()

Dim a As Long

For a = 4 To 20
    If Range("H" & a).Value Like "*nice*" Then
        GoTo Clean
    Else
        GoTo pre
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If (Range("H" & a).Value = "*nice*") Then
```

change to

```
If instr(Range("H" & a).Value,"nice")>0 Then
```

Comment: You don't even need the >0 for this to work. Don't you also need a 1 as the first parameter in the InStr()?

Comment: @CallumDA,the first parameter is unnecessary, instr will start from the first letter in VBA. You can try that if you don't believe.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, although I'd probably call it optional rather than *unnecessary* :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()
    Dim a As Long

    For a = 4 To 20
        If InStr(1, Range("H" & a).Value, "nice") Then
            GoTo Clean
        Else
            GoTo pre
        End If
    Next code here

End Sub
```

Just one **big reminder** - try to avoid goto statements, as far as they are considered really bad practise in VBA develelopment. What you can do is to create another sub routine and to call it from the code.

Comment: its still skipping clean an jumping to pre even tho the range containe "nice" :(

Comment: there are many words in the range and ig "nice" is in them then it needs to go to clean. e.x.
"the boy is very nice today" - this has the word "nice" so go to clean code

Comment: What is the address of the range?

Comment: address? like from where to where? "h4:h20"

Comment: You can write `stop` before `goto clean` and check whether it stops.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're looking for the string *nice*. The asterisks are not being treated as wildcards.

You can use the [`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator, this will then allow you to use asterisks as wildcards:

```
If (Range("H" & a).Value Like "*nice*") Then
```

You can then expand on this; if you only want the word 'nice' to match, and not other words that contain 'nice', you can use the below:

```
If " " & UCase((Range("H" & a).Value) & " " Like "[!A-Z]*NICE*[!A-Z]"
```

Whilst using `Like` is slower than using `InStr`, it allows more complex matching, due to it's similar syntax to RegEx.

I would also suggest, that instead of using the `GoTo` statement, you use a function or sub procedure for each piece of code that you wish to run.

Comment: idk how to do that so im using "go to"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and for me the best solution was the following.

```
If Not Range("H4:H20").Find(What:="nice", LookAt:=xlPart) Is Nothing Then
```

If an exact match is sought, the **xlWhole** keyword must be used.